# Carregar imagem alternativa em caso de não ter a imagem correta

Tags: php

Eu tenho esse código que carrega a imagem do jogador de acordo com o seu nome, é possível complementar esse código carregando uma foto default, quando o código não encontrar a foto do jogador?

```
$player_img = "players/" . $row['LastName'] . "_" . $row['FirstName'] . ".png";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para correr o código normalmente basta redefinir "$player_img" caso a referencia não aponte para uma imagem no servidor.

```
// receber a referencia noralmente
$player_img = "players/" . $row['LastName'] . "_" . $row['FirstName'] . ".png";
// verificar se não existe
if( !file_exists($player_img) ){
   // definir uma imagem padrão
   $player_img = "players/default.png";
}
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

**Resposta:**

```
$player_img = "players/" . $row['LastName'] . "_" . $row['FirstName'] . ".png";
if (file_exists($player_img)){
    echo '<img src="'.$player_img.'"></img>';
} else {
    echo '<img src="players/default.png"></img>';
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado por ajudar, o código funcionou mas a foto está carregando no topo da pagina e não no lugar aonde deveria carregar.

Comment: Recomendo criar uma outra pergunta no SO para isso.